# hundred-tab friendly Mozilla w/ no continuous javascript

Tags: firefox, performance, javascript, tabbed-browsing

I often have hundreds of tabs open in many windows in Mozilla, and, after a while, it starts consuming significant amount of CPU for these dormant pages, and each new window and page takes a very long time to load.

Is there a set of settings which can be adjusted, to make Mozilla SeaMonkey and Firefox more friendly to having hundreds of tabs open?

I'm thinking that it's mostly all kinds of persistent JavaScript that is affecting performance; unfortunately, turning off JavaScript in full is not realistic, but perhaps there are some settings to turn off all sorts of crazy event handlers that are still running even when a page is out of focus?

Comment: *Hundreds?* That has to be using a tremendous amount of memory and CPU time, even when those pages are truly dormant. Surely you don't need that many for your own actual use and are actually using them to test something, in which case you could automate it.

Comment: @EdCottrell, 10 windows, with 10 tabs each, sounds like an average number of things I often have open.  No reason inactive windows have to consume any CPU time at all, and memory is cheap.